# ¿Cómo puedo evitar un INSERT en una tabla en que el valor de la columna 1 ya se encuentre en la columna 2 o viceversa?

Tags: sql-server, trigger, constraints

[image: Esta es una imagen de lo que quiero evitar:]

```
Create Table XXX (C1 smallint not null, C2 smallint not null)  

Insert into XXX (C1,C2) values (10,20)  
Insert into XXX (C1,C2) values (10,30)  
Insert into XXX (C1,C2) values (40,50)
```

El objetivo es que el TRIGGER o lo que recomendeis, impida un INSERT o UPDATE de un valor en una columna diferente de la otra, si ya contiene ese valor.  El mismo VALOR no debe poder existir en las 2 columnas.

Pretendo que no permita realizar los siguientes INSERTS:

```
Insert into XXX (C1,C2) values (50,60)  
Insert into XXX (C1,C2) values (80,10)
```

pues el valor 50 (para insertar en C1) ya existe C2 y
y el valor 10 (para insertar en C2) ya existe C1

**Solucionado**

No entiendo porqué no funcionaba el TRIGGER sin PRIMARY KEY en C1+C2. No lo había puesto por simplificar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He añadido también la opcion UPDATE para que controle las 2 situaciones, quedando:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TXXX] ON [dbo].[XXX]  
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS 
    IF EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM XXX x
                JOIN inserted i ON x.C1 = i.C2
                                OR x.C2 = i.C1)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        RAISERROR( 'El valor de C1 ya existe en C2 o viceversa',16,1 );
 END;
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda prestada.

Answer (score 1):

El trigger tiene que hacer uso de la tabla virtual inserted y compararlo con la tabla real que aun no tiene los valores que se van a insertar. Podría quedar algo similar a esto.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TXXX ON XXX
FOR INSERT
AS
 IF EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM XXX x
            JOIN inserted i ON x.C1 = i.C2
                            OR x.C2 = i.C1)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN;
    RAISERROR( 'El valor de C1 ya existe en C2 o viceversa',16,1 );
END;
```

Comment: +1 agregaría a tu solución la recomendación de índices para cada una de las columnas

Comment: Sugerir índices sin conocer realmente la estructura de la tabla me parece muy peligroso. Pero ciertamente pueden ser útiles.

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería el peligro de "Recomendar" o "sugerir" el uso de índices? veo más peligroso el eventual table scan en una operación de insert.

Comment: El aumentar la cantidad de almacenamiento necesario, reducir la velocidad de operaciones DML, ambas cosas sin tener la seguridad de que los índices se vayan a utilizar debido a un mal diseño. Si te refieres a sugerir el uso de índices, me parece bien. Si te refieres a sugerir índices específicos es cuando me parece riesgoso.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos caminos para hacer lo que pides, restringir a la hora de hacer la consulta, en este caso el `INSERT` con un `SELECT` previo, o restringir la columna a un valor único.

Creo que modificar la columna es el mejor camino puesto que así el modelado y la estructura de la BBDD es el correcto.

Esto se consigue creando en la columna un índice de clave única con el siguiente esquema:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nombreindice
ON nombretabla (nombrecolumna);
```

Comment: Igual no me he expresado bien.  Un valor puede estar varias veces en una columna en diferentes registros, pero no podrá estar en la otra columna en ningún registro. Creo que UNIQUE INDEX no sirve. Pienso que habria que desarrollar un TRIGGER que lo impida pero no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: Tienes razón, leyendote de nuevo comprendo lo quieres decir. Puedes hacerlo con un TRIGGER, pero te obligas a eliminar el registro que acabas de insertar si cumple la condición, algo que personalmente no me gusta.O realizar la inserción a traves de un Procedimiento Almacenado y ahí realizar las comprobaciones necesarias previo INSERT, ahora edito la respuesta con esta última opción.